# Strangely Query String is disappeared on live server

Tags: c#, asp.net

Maybe this is a very normal behaviour or I am missing something very basic. I have a page named Default.aspx and it is set to Default page for my web application. On this page there is a dropdownlist for categories and when I select any value then response.redirect is called for the same page and category id is passed as a query string. Now everything work just fine when I test the application locally. When I publish the website on the server and call the website with url www.mywebsite.com then the default page is displayed but page name is not displayed. I have no issue with it but without the page name my response.redirect stops working. So just to summarize all this in following lines,

www.mysite.com

```
// On Selected Index Changed
Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx?catId="+ ddlCategory.SelectedItem.Value);
```

The Url should be for first category

```
www.mysite.com/Default.aspx?catId=1
```

but it is not changing and on postback www.mysite.com is displayed.

However if in the address bar I have,

```
www.mysite.com/Default.aspx
```

and now if I change the selected index of drop down then it works fine and the url becomes,

```
www.mysite.com/Default.aspx?catId=1
```

Now I don't know whether this question was asked already because I don't even know what the issue is and what should I search.

Update:
Now this is reproduced in the local system also. It seems that when the page name Default.aspx is not present in the address bar with url then SelectedIndexChanged is not called. If Default.aspx is in the address bar then SelectedIndexChanged is fired.

Comment: So just to understand: 

 1. You go to your website default page and it loads correctly including the drop down menu
 2. You select an item from the drop down menu and it directs you to the **incorrect** page
 3. If you manually type in www.mysite.com/Default.aspx?catId=1 it correctly will load the page though.

Can you post the rest of your view code?

Comment: No the page is not redirecting to the incorrect page. (1) - I call the website www.mysite.com The default page is displayed.    (2) - I change the category by changing dropdownlist value. It calls Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx?catdId=" +2);    (3) - The page is redirected but again www.mysite.com is displayed and no query string is with the address.  (4) - But if the url is www.mysite.com/Default.aspx and now I change the dropdown selection then query string is present.

Comment: Also note that I am redirecting to the same page not a different page. I am just appending the query string.

Comment: Some web browser's mask it, it still exist. You could run a test, query query string then see if it returns null

Comment: @Greg, Thats the whole point. I have to use query string for operation and it is found null  and not masked.

Comment: Examine all the code that runs by setting breakpoints. You may find that you have some code that is forcing the page to reload or performing some kind of redirect.

Comment: @mason I have already examined the code by placing the breakpoints but as I said breakpoint is not called on SelectedIndexChanged event when there is no page name. I wonder if someone having experience with url rewriting has some experience on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I am still unable to find the exact reason for the behaviour that I have mentioned in my question but I have applied a workaround. I am now not calling the SelectedIndexChange event from code behind, instead I am using Javascript to redirect to the same page with query string.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function CategoryChanged() {
       var ddlReport = document.getElementById("<%=ddlCategory.ClientID%>");
       window.location = 'Default.aspx?catId=' + ddlCategory.value;
    }
</script>
```

And called this on onchange of my dropdownlist,

```
onchange="CategoryChanged()"
```

Beside this solution I would love to know that why the code behind event was not called when page name is not mentioned in the url. So if anyone has any idea do share their thoughts.

Comment: This solution is superior anyways: if you don't need to involve the server, then don't! This avoids an unecessary request to the server, page life cycle, and response containing redirect.